# Why does this also return None in the end

Tags: python-3.x, csv

So I have these two functions in python:

```
import csv

#========== reader ==========#
def Test_reader(target_file):
        
    with open(target_file, newline='') as csvfile:
    
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    
        for row in spamreader:
            print(', '.join(row))
            
#========== DictReader ==========#
def Test_DictReader(target_file, dict_id):

    # 'first_name' will be the dictionary's first row ID
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    with open(target_file, "r", newline='') as csvfile:
        
        spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,fieldnames=fieldnames)

        for row in spamreader:
            print(row[dict_id])


print(Test_reader("names.csv"))
# Or
print(Test_DictReader("names.csv","first_name"))
```

There are no errors but it also prints "None"

Test_reader prints:

```
.....................................
.....................................
Corey,Smith,coreysmith@bogusemail.com
Mary,Patterson,marypatterson@bogusemail.com
Jane,Stuart,janestuart@bogusemail.com
Travis,Arnold,travisarnold@bogusemail.com
John,Robinson,johnrobinson@bogusemail.com
Travis,Arnold,travisarnold@bogusemail.com
None
```

Test_DictReader prints:

```
.....................................
.....................................
coreysmith@bogusemail.com
marypatterson@bogusemail.com
janestuart@bogusemail.com
travisarnold@bogusemail.com
johnrobinson@bogusemail.com
travisarnold@bogusemail.com
None
```

the csv file "names.csv" goes like this.

first_name,last_name,email 
John,Doe,john-doe@bogusemail.com 
Mary,Smith-Robinson,maryjacobs@bogusemail.com 
Dave,Smith,davesmith@bogusemail.com 
Jane,Stuart,janestuart@bogusemail.com 
. . .

There are no spare spaces/lines.

Comment: Every function in Python returns `None` if it doesn't explicitly return something else.

Comment: But i print only the rows. If i were to not print anything, would it still show "None" when calling the function?

Comment: Usually your IDE will print the return value of your function if you don't explicitly do something else with it (like assign it to a variable or pass it to another function) but it makes an exception for `None` and doesn't print anything.  Since you told it to print the return value, that's what it did.